# Problems writing the memset function

Tags: c

I am writing the `memset` function and my code is below, I am having a problem

```
void* memsetFun(void* pointer, int c, int size) {

  if ( pointer != NULL && size > 0 ) {

    unsigned char* pChar =  pointer;


    int i = 0;

      for ( i = 0; i < size; ++i) {

      unsigned char temp = (unsigned char) c;

      *pChar++ = temp; // or pChar[i] = temp (they both don't work)

    }
  }  
    return pointer;


}
```

I also tried pChar[i] = the value we want and still not working. It gives me some trash numbers that do not make any sense.

And I am calling it:

```
memsetFun(address, num, size);
printf("value at %p is %d\n", address, *((int*) address));
```

Where I call the address (I just input the address)

For example, if you to print the chars ( c ) it prints like a weird char that looks like ( for the value 4 )

```
0 0
0 4
```

Comment: Did you make sure that size was non-zero in the caller?

Comment: What is `p`? I assume you mean `pointer`?

Comment: Why is your prototype different from the ANSI C's `memset`?  You should use `size_t` for the third parameter.  Also, please post the actual code (copy-paste), don't type it here.  What's "p"?  Finally, post minimal code that shows errors.

Comment: Yeah p is pointer and I have it as pointer actually sorry :)

Comment: Show us how you use it: the values you call it with and the values you get in the caller.

Comment: Tried your function locally and it worked. Are you sure you are not calling it with pointer = NULL and/or size <= 0?

Comment: If you're writing *the* memset function, you should not be checking for null pointer - the real memset doesn't do that.

Comment: Well the specs ask me to do that :)

Comment: Regarding the null and the size, the code takes care of that :)

Comment: Can you show us a *complete* program that shows the error?  What's `num` and what's `size`? What do you expect the output to be?  I think your function is correct but you have a wrong idea of what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Try printing the value in hexadecimal: `printf("value at %p is %08x\n", address, *((int*) address))`

Comment: It is a full code, but what it does related to memset is posted here. Num is 2 and size is 4 (that's what I choose)

Comment: It is *not* full code, because it does not compile.  Post *full* code.

Comment: Ohh no, I mean it is a huge code, I am not able to post it but that is the part of the code. It is printing weird chars for ( c ).
For example if the value i want is 4 it gives me a char that looks like:
0 0
0 4

Comment: ...You mean you're setting it 0x4, and you're expecting your printf statement to output the decimal digit "4"?

Comment: Look above (my entry) for how it prints c

Comment: You should be able to separate out parts of your program that exhibit the problem.  That's why I said *minimal* program.  So, your *minimal* program will include the function, and a `main()` which defines `address`, `num`, and `size`, calls the function, and prints the result.  We would be able to compile such a program and also see how *exactly* are you calling it.

Comment: The problem is false expectations. He's setting the memory to 0x4, and printing that out just fine (as evidenced by the appropriate "unprintable character" glyph), but is erroneously expecting to get the decimal digit printed back.

Comment: -1 for very poorly phrased question, and lack of detail provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me and several people here have commented that it works on their system.

So the obvious thing to do is to debug it - that's a skill that will come in handy quite a bit in future :-) You should learn it *now*.

What does the following code output when you run it?

```
void* memsetFun(void* pointer, int c, int size) {
    printf("A %x %d %d\n", pointer, c, size);
    if ( pointer != NULL && size > 0 ) {
        printf("B\n");
        unsigned char* pChar =  pointer;
        int i = 0;
        for ( i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            printf("C %d (%d)", i, *pChar);
            unsigned char temp = (unsigned char) c;
            *pChar++ = temp; // or pChar[i] = temp (they both don't work)
            printf(" -> (%d)", i, *(pChar-1));
        }
    }  
    printf("D\n");
    return pointer;
}
```

From the output, it should be clear what paths the code is taking and what your parameters are (which will greatly assist the debugging process).

*Update:*

If you're filling your memory block with anything other than zeros and using this:

```
printf("value at %p is %d\n", address, *((int*) address));
```

to print it out, you *will* get strange results.

You're basically asking for a number of those bytes to be interpreted as an integer. So, for example, if you filled it with `0x02` bytes and you have a 4-byte integer type, you will get the integer `0x02020202` (33686018), *not* `0x02` as you may expect. If you want to see what the first *character* value is, use:

```
printf("value at %p is %d\n", address, *((char*) address));
```

And based on your *latest* question update:

> For example, if you to print the chars ( c ) it prints like a weird char that looks like ( for the value 4 )
>   0 0
>   0 4

If that's a single character and you're printing it as a character, there's probably nothing wrong at all. Many output streams will give you that for a control character (CTRL-D in this case, ASCII code 4). If you instead filled it with ASCII code 0x30 (48), you would see the character '0' or ASCII 0x41 (65) would give you 'A'.

Comment: I changed it but it is still giving me the same error ( and yes it gives me the value 33686018 when it is supposed to be 2 but even after changing that code to your code :( )

Comment: 33686018 is 0x02020202, which is 2 repeated 4 times.  Everything is fine, except your understanding of memory. :-)

Comment: Thanks Alok :) that's why I am trying to learn more. Anyway, I know that 33686018 is 0x02020202 but the problem is why I am getting it.

Comment: @unknown, have a look at the section of this answer immediately followint "Update:". You have a memory block where every character is 0x02 but you are printing an integer from that memory block. An integer in your case is 4 characters, *not* one. That's why you're getting the value 0x02020202. If you print a *char* from that block, you'll get the value you expect.

Comment: `memset` can only set one value per byte.  So, given 0x02, it sets that value on all the bytes.  Later, you *interpret* 4 of these bytes as an `int`, and print it.  If you interpreted 2 of these bytes, you would get `514` as output.  So, your interpretation was wrong.  Also, *please* see my answer to your question: it has useful information not only for this question, but for all the questions you want to ask in the future.  Thanks!

Comment: Just correcting the last printf, the format to print a char as a signed integer is %hhd, and as unsigned is %hhu.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out already, your function works as it should. Here is a complete example:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

void* memsetFun(void* pointer, int c, int size) {
    if ( pointer != NULL && size > 0 ) {
        unsigned char* pChar =  pointer;
        int i = 0;
        for ( i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            unsigned char temp = (unsigned char) c;
            *pChar++ = temp; // or pChar[i] = temp (they both don't work)
        }
    }
    return pointer;
}

int main() {
    // Your memset
    char a[10];
    memsetFun(a, 'A', sizeof(a));

    // Uses system memset for verification
    char b[10];
    memset(b, 'A', sizeof(b));

    assert(sizeof(a) == sizeof(b));
    assert(memcmp(a, b, sizeof(b)) == 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`return p;` prevents this from compiling:  `p` is not defined.

A minor efficiency issue—in practice it would have little effect, since any good compiler would rearrange it, but coding perfectionists wouldn't allow it to remain—the assignment to `temp` is inside the loop, but it is the same assignment every time.  That is, the assignment to `temp` can be moved before the loop.

Comment: I edited it to pointer :) thank you but that is not the problem, that was just a copy, paste issue

Answer (score 0):

You return `p`, which isn't defined/doesn't point to anything in particular.  Maybe you meant `pointer`?

Answer (score 0):

The code is logically correct. With the `p` => `pointer` change it works correctly.

Clarify how exactly it is "not working". Perhaps you are not understanding what it is supposed to do?

Comment: it is putting trash numbers into the values, so when u check the value (when u asked the value to be 2 for example), you check the value for the bytes assigned and the values come out to be random numbers

Comment: @unknown Can we see the code you are using to check the values?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting trash numbers because you are casting from an int (4 bytes) to an unsigned char (1 byte), so if c > 255 or < 0 you won't be memsetting the values you are expecting to be.

Comment: c is guaranteed to be between 0 and 255

Answer (score 0):

Your function, **as is**, works for me.

I suppose you're calling it wrong. I call it like this

```
char a[100];
memsetFun(a, 0, sizeof a);
int b[100];
memsetFun(b, 0, sizeof b);
```

How are you calling your `memsetFun()`?

*Edit*

With

```
int b[100];
memsetFun(b, 9, sizeof b);
```

as an int is made up of 4 bytes (on my system) each value will be set to `0x09090909` or `151587081`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a test if your program setting the memory of an int vector of 5 elements setting with the value 0x01.

The problem here is that you are iterating in a vector of int for example (which is 4 bytes) but iterating over it using char pointer arithmetic (1 byte). If you want to memset 0x01 for example you will write this number per value in the vector: 00000001000000010000000100000001
which gives me the same value using the original memset.

Comment: `memset` in the C language is defined to take `int` as the second parameter.  You are assuming that an `int` is 4 bytes - this need not be true.  Finally, I don't know what you're trying to say with the bit-pattern.

Comment: Well, run the program yourself. Suppose a vector int v[5]; after that memset(v, 0x01, sizeof(int)*5); memset will write 0x01010101 in your vector which seems to be wrong (some people may expect 0x01 per position) but its not true. 
Yes you pass a int for the value, but a pointer void as the mem buffer.

Comment: About the bit pattern, as you may now 1 in decimal is equal to 0x01 in hex which is equal to 00000001 in binary ;). That big binary pattern, with some effort, is the number 0x01010101 in hex or 16843009 in decimal

Comment: The way `memset` is defined, it *should* set the memory to 0x01010101 in this case.  `memset`, by definition, writes only *one* value to all the memory locations that it writes to.

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what it's supposed to do. Your function is working perfectly fine. The value "0x4" is *not* the ASCII character '4'.