# How to get a FILE pointer from a file descriptor?

Tags: c, posix, mkstemp

I'm playing around with `mkstemp()`, which provides a file descriptor, but I want to generate formatted output via `fprintf()`. Is there an easy way to transform the file descriptor provided by `mkstemp()` into a `FILE *` structure that is suitable for use with `fprintf()`?

Comment: And the inverse: [How can I convert a file pointer ( FILE* ) to a file descriptor (fd)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167298/how-can-i-convert-a-file-pointer-file-to-a-file-descriptor-fd)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Use [`fdopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/fdopen.html):

```
FILE* fp = fdopen(fd, "w");
```

Comment: And to get the file descriptor from a FILE* use `fileno()` : http://linux.die.net/man/3/fileno

Comment: if `fd` was opened with some flags (like `O_NONBLOCK`) -- what will happen with them after `fdopen` opens it with new flags? Will they be `xor`-ed together or substituted?

Comment: Not available in ANSI C.

Comment: @jww: File descriptors are not ANSI C to begin with.

Comment: and is there a way to close a file with the fd?

Comment: If you mean close(fd), that's not a good idea. fclose(fp) should be used to make sure any buffered output (if any) is written.

Comment: is it bad in any way to call `fdopen` multiple times? (assuming it happens inside some function which gets called again and again)

Comment: You don't want to fdopen() the same file descriptor twice. Each instance will have separate buffers that will cause your input/output to get messed up.

Comment: @RichardPennington I think multiple `fdopen` calls are fine depending on what underlies the file descriptor. For a tty or a socket this may actually be desirable since ANSI C has requirements for `fseek`/`fgetpos`/`fflush` calls between input and output. Here it seems different streams for input and output are the best way to go. This essentially happens with `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr` anyway on a terminal device - the file descriptors refer to the same file description. See https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24261206/Using-fdopen-twice-on-an-open-stream-socket-file-descriptor.html

Comment: @xealits The options for the FILE* have to be within the scope of the already open file descriptor. So if you have opened fd with read only, and the FILE* with write only, it should throw an exception.

For more info refer to https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.bpxbd00/rtfdo.htm

Comment: @TjadClark "it should throw an exception" - that would be difficult seeing as fdopen() is a C function and C has no native exceptions mechanism.

Answer (score 32):

`FILE* f = fdopen(d, "w");`

man fdopen output:

> SYNOPSIS

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *
fdopen(int fildes, const char *mode);
```

> The `fdopen()` function associates a stream with the existing file descriptor, `fildes`. The mode of the stream must be compatible with the mode of the file descriptor.  When the stream is closed via `fclose(3)`, `fildes` is closed also.

Comment: Not available in ANSI C.

Comment: For more clarity, refer to https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.bpxbd00/rtfdo.htm

Answer (score -8):

There is no standard way of doing this (or the reverse) as the C Standard has nothing to say about file descriptors. Your specific platform may or may not provide such a mechanism.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "standard". POSIX is a standard.

Comment: though, The fdopen() function conforms to IEEE Std 1003.1-1988 (``POSIX.1'').

Comment: The question was about file descriptors. ;-)

Comment: @Neil > you might be right, you didn't help the OP with your answer

Comment: @Gregory I helped him assuming that he wants to write portable code. And downvoting technically correct answers is not good practice.

Comment: @Richard The question is tagged as C, not Posix. Posix is a platform, not a language, standard.

Comment: @Neil > I didn't vote down, indeed there is nothing wrong in what you said.

Comment: @Neil > the question being tagged as C doesn't mean "tell me the holly truth about the C standard" but rather "I'm coding in C, I fail at doing this, please tell me whether it is possible and how?"

Comment: There is a `posix` tag here on SO, with 193 questions.  Having said that, I think Neil's answer is correct.  More people should be using `posix` tag.  And it's a good idea to remind people what exactly "C" is.  While we're at it, we should make people realize that there's nothing like "C/C++", and that these are two different languages.

Comment: @Neil > it looks like you have fans though, as several of my answers are being downvoted right now :)

Comment: I'm backing away slowly... Now turning and running away.

Comment: @Gregory: For the record, it wasn't me. There are some weird downvoting issues here on SO. My posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898371/problems-writing-the-memset-function/1898515#1898515 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938491/memory-corruption/1938530#1938530 were downvoted, and I don't know why!

Comment: I agree that there's no standard way of doing this, but the OP's mention of `mkstemp` implies that non-standard solutions are acceptable in this particular instance.  In that case, however, he should have added the `posix` tag (which I see has since been added).

Comment: @Neil, and the purpose of the Net and the meaning of life. You would make more sense if you've said that you are of different opinion. I also doubt SO is all about hairsplitting over standards. And it's not very practical to rely on tagging skills of someone with an SO-experience corresponding to the reputation of 23.

Comment: Not sure why this fellow is getting downvoted. ANSI C does not have `fdopen`, so there's no way to convert a file descriptor to a `FILE*` in a base system. You'd need a different standard to get the functionality.