# "invalid conversion from 'FILE* {aka _iobuf}' to 'int'" error

Tags: c++, windows

I want to change size of *.txt file, which is created before. For this i use `chsize`. 
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE *wfile; 
    wfile = fopen("test.exe", "a");
    chsize(wfile, 1024); //error is here
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

And here goes the error:

> [Error] invalid conversion from 'FILE* {aka _iobuf*}' to 'int'
>   [-fpermissive]

**Q:** What is wrong here? I opened the file with `fopen` right how it explained in the internets.

**Q2:** I love Windows as a OS, but I don't want to learn Windows API for C++ or something like that. Is there a option to use something portable?

Comment: `chsize()` takes an integer for the file descriptor. You can't convert a `FILE*` to that -- http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref%2Ftopic%2Fc%2Fchsize.html

Comment: `file.close();` is bad as well, should be `fclose(wfile);`

Comment: **A2** to **Q2**: use `<iostream>`

Comment: @PiotrS. I don't know if iostream actually does everything a file API can do. I'm guessing that boost::filesystem would do everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First parameter for chsize is file descriptor not FILE*.

You can use function "fileno".

[How can I convert a file pointer ( FILE* fp ) to a file descriptor (int fd)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167298/how-can-i-convert-a-file-pointer-file-to-a-file-descriptor-fd)